# TYPO3 How to set usergroup for fe_user?

Tags: typo3

I have TYPO3 version 7.6.18.

I am making custom registration and I adding user in my code in controller:

```
$this->userRepository->add($user);
```

I need to set usergroup

I tried:

```
$user->setUsergroup(1);
```

But it calling error:

```
PHP Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Domain\Model\FrontendUser::setUsergroup() must be an instance of TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\ObjectStorage, integer given, called in /home/abenteuer/public_html/typo3conf/ext/feusersplus/Classes/Controller/NewController.php on line 68 and defined in /home/abenteuer/public_html/typo3/sysext/extbase/Classes/Domain/Model/FrontendUser.php line 192
```

I understand that I should pass argument to setUsergroup() which must be instance of TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\ObjectStorage, but I don't know how to do it.

Help me please, anybody. I want to set usergroup, for example, with uid 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need a separate repository for user groups (or start with the existing `FrontendUserGroupRepository`) to retrieve the group(s):

```
$userGroup = $this->userGroupRepository->findByIdentifier(1);
```

Then you can simply do the following:

```
$user->addUsergroup($userGroup);
```

Afterwards add the `$user` to your repository just like before.

Comment: Thank you very much! But now I see another error! 

PHP Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Domain\Model\FrontendUser::setUsergroup() must be an instance of TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\ObjectStorage, instance of In2code\Femanager\Domain\Model\UserGroup given, called in /home/abenteuer/public_html/typo3conf/ext/feusersplus/Classes/Controller/NewController.php on line 70 and defined in /home/abenteuer/public_html/typo3/sysext/extbase/Classes/Domain/Model/FrontendUser.php line 192

Comment: I also tried addUsergroup and I get error:

PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function attach() on a non-object in /home/abenteuer/public_html/typo3/sysext/extbase/Classes/Domain/Model/FrontendUser.php

Comment: @Mikael If you want to use `setUsergroup()` you need to prepare an `ObjectStorage` instance yourself. The error for `addUsergroup` should not occur since the `ObjectStorage` for the `usergroup` property is created in the `FrontendUser` constructor.

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment currently, but something you forgot, so i create an answer.

You can only use `$this->userGroupRepository->findByIdentifier(1);` if you inject the Repository to your Controller with the following code:

```
/**
 * userGroupRepository
 *
 * @var \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Domain\Repository\FrontendUserGroupRepository
 * @inject
 */
protected $userGroupRepository = null;
```